# Responsive liste in Cordova using RPage for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do a responsive list using [RPage for bootstrap](http://auxiliary.github.io/rpage/)
but the js file does not response in my cordova app ,

**the script:**

```
<script src="js/responsive-paginate.js"></script>  
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pagination").rPage();
       });

    </script>
```

**the html:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#"> << </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> >> </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem i should add the JQUERY SRC before adding responsive paginate
it should be like :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsive-paginate.js"></script>
```